# How can you make custom counter display types?

Tags: counters, calculations, exam

I'm a comp sci prof working on an exam for my students in LaTeX, using the [exam class](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/exam). I like to throw in a few in-jokes here and there. Unfortunately, the class breaks if you try to use 0-indexing on the questions (i.e. set the `\thequestion` counter to an initial value of -1). So...I thought I'd bypass the problem by making a custom counter *display*, like `\alph`,`\roman`, etc., that just outputs the arabic number one less than the counter.

However, this requires some heavy-duty variable evaluation. I'd like to do something like this:

```
\renewcommand{\thequestion}{\arabic{question - 1}}
```

But I don't understand function evaluation in LaTeX very well. Does anybody have an idea, or can at least point me where to start?

Comment: Use `\setcounter{question}{-1}` at the start and *inside* the `questions` environment, and things should be fine. Don't tinker with `\thequestion`.

Comment: No go. That numbers the questions themselves properly, but breaks the \gradetable. (The author has said that it's a known issue that he should fix, but he hasn't had the time.) The resulting table is missing Question #0, and has an additional Question ?? at the end.

Good thought, though.

Comment: I do not quite understand, do you only need the value of the counter displayed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All counter representation commands like `\arabic` or `\alph` call an associated internal command (`\@arabic` or `\@alph`) that takes the number represented by the counter as input.  For a counter `<counter>` this is always a TeX `\count` named `\c@<ounter>`.  The scheme is always as follows:

```
\def\cntformat#1{\expandafter\@cntformat\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\@cntformat#1{<do something with integer #1 that formats the number>}
```

where `\cntformat` stands for a command like `\arabic`.

---

Our user command now could look like this (using `\newcommand*` instead of `\def`):

```
\newcommand*\arabicminusone[1]{\expandafter\@arabicminusone\csname c@#1\endcsname}
```

This command takes an argument (`#1`, the counter name) from which the associated count is built (`\csname c@#1\endcsname`). This is then the argument to our internal command `\@arabicminusone`. In order to build the `\c@<counter>` *before* is is parsed by `\@arabicminusone` the latter needs to be preceded by `\expandafter`.

The internal command should take an integer as argument and simply substract one.  There are a few possibilities to do this, one of them is e-TeX's `\numexpr ... \relax`. The `\relax` is not mandatory, strictly speaking, but will do no harm. It prevents `\numexpr` from scanning further ahead until the number expression ends and is removed from the input stream.

```
\newcommand*\@arabicminusone[1]{\the\numexpr(#1)-1\relax}
```

With these two definitions you can now use it to format a counter:

```
\newcounter{test}
\setcounter{test}{8}
\arabicminusone{test}% will print `7'
```

---

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{exam}

% make @ a letter so we can use it in names of command sequences:
\makeatletter
% call the internal \c@<counter> command and apply number formatting:
\newcommand*\arabicminusone[1]{\expandafter\@arabicminusone\csname c@#1\endcsname}
% number formatting:
\newcommand*\@arabicminusone[1]{\the\numexpr(#1)-1\relax}
% make @ other again:
\makeatother

\renewcommand*\thequestion{\arabicminusone{question}}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
  \addpoints
  \question[5] foo
  \question[4] bar
\end{questions}

\gradetable

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think this one does exactly what I want. Thank you!

Could you explain the lines between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`? It's obvious that you're defining a counter-printing style called `arabicminusone`, but I'm not sure what the two `\def` commands are doing.

Thanks again.

Comment: @AdamSmith I added some explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another Idea, if you only want to throw in fake questions, that shall not appear in the `\gradetable`.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\newcounter{display}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
  \addpoints
  \setcounter{display}{\value{question}}
  \item[\arabic{display}.] (10 points) Fake question...
  \question[10] A foo question
  \question[10] A bar question
  \setcounter{display}{\value{question}}
  \item[\arabic{display}.] (10 points) Annutha fake question...
\end{questions}

\gradetable
\end{document}
```