# Leading zeros when cross referencing

Tags: macros, cross-referencing

I have a custom counter and output it with leading zeros. When I reference it, I get some real strange output, but the enumeration itself works.

Preamble:

```
\newcounter{reqcount}
\setcounter{reqcount}{3}

\newcommand{\threedigits}[1]{%
    \ifnum #1<100 0\fi%
    \ifnum #1<10 0\fi%
    \number#1}
```

Document

```
\refstepcounter{reqcount}\label{req}
[DR-\threedigits{\arabic{reqcount}}] % Works, outputs [DR-001]
[DR-{\ref{req}}] % Outputs [DR-4<100 04<10 004]
```

---

Someone posted this answer but it was removed. I don't know why, but the code below works and the above does not.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{reqcount}
\setcounter{reqcount}{0}

\newcommand{\threedigits}[1]%
{%
    \ifnum #1<10 00%
    \else%
        \ifnum #1<100 0%
        \fi%
    \fi%
    \number#1%
}

\newcommand\DR[1]% macro to typeset a new DR item
{%
    \refstepcounter{reqcount}\label{DR:#1}%
    [DR-\threedigits{\value{reqcount}}]%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\refDR[1]% macro to cross-reference to a particular DR item
{%
        [DR-\expandafter\threedigits\ref{DR:#1}]%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

%.... 88 DR items later
\setcounter{reqcount}{1}

\DR{foo} blah blah

As seen in~\refDR{foo}, blah blah blah

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You got the code with 4 as argument #1 instead of the calculated result. I guess we should see more of your code, how you actually use it, as @egreg said.

Comment: This is basically an MWE. Feel free to add the three lines of codes as necessary.
There were an answer here yesterday that I got working, but it was removed before I was able to mark it as an answer. If the user adds the answer again, I will happily accept it.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a MWE.

Comment: Important information is missing like how you redefined `\thereqcount` (which you obviously have: otherwise `[DR-{\ref{req}}]` should print something like »[DR-4]«) so this is _not_ an MWE

Comment: Never claimed it to be an MWE either (and it's definitely not working). Anyway, added the anonymous (slightly modified) solution, hope it helps someone.

Comment: @Oscar yes you did (»This is basically an MWE«). _Working_ doesn't mean it shouldn't produce errors but to allow others to _reproduce_ the issues. Have you even followed the link (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: It was a joke. Also please note the basically. Thanks for the input anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I don't completely understand what you actually need I still want to show an alternative to the accepted solution you added to your question.

I'd define a counter representation command (like `\arabic`) that prints the value of a counter with at least three digits and redefine the corresponding `\the<counter>` macro to use it. For this two commands need to be defined (see [How can you make custom counter display types?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124980)):

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\threedigits[1]{\expandafter\@threedigits\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand*\@threedigits[1]{%
  \ifnum#1<100 0\fi
  \ifnum#1<10 0\fi
  \number#1%
}
\makeatother
```

With this you for example say `\threedigits{section}` or in your case `\threedigits{reqcount}`. If you then redefine `\thereqcount`

```
\renewcommand*\thereqcount{[DR-\threedigits{reqcount}]}
```

You can simply use the standard `\ref` to get the desired output:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\threedigits[1]{\expandafter\@threedigits\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand*\@threedigits[1]{%
  \ifnum#1<100 0\fi
  \ifnum#1<10 0\fi
  \number#1%
}
\makeatother

\newcounter{reqcount}
\renewcommand*\thereqcount{[DR-\threedigits{reqcount}]}
\newcommand*\DR{\refstepcounter{reqcount}\thereqcount}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{reqcount}{37}

\DR\label{DR:foo} blah blah

As seen in~\ref{DR:foo}, blah blah blah

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Works as well, and is more elegant than the other suggestion.

Comment: I noted that adding `%` after the `\fi`'s removed some compilation errors I got in (rare) cases.

Comment: @Oscar spaces after the `\fi`'s are ignored anyway (as they are after each control sequence word) so adding `%` is equivalent to not adding them. The cause of the errors you get must be something else...

Comment: I believe the extra `%`causes the compiler to ignore the row break, which in some cases may or may not cause compilation errors. I believe [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40946/why-the-end-of-line-in-macro-definitions) might be relevant. I think I had some package that caused this.

Comment: @Oscar see also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19922/5049 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5049 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34844/5049

Comment: would you explain newbies what does `\expandafter` and `\csname` are and why are they used here? I read docs and I'm still unclear...

Comment: @Igoru there are a numbers of questions with answers dealing with those, e.g., http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451/ and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39380 probably more

Comment: I read those but that still seems a little bit complicated. I asked that because I was interested in not creating two custom padding commands, but rather using `\padzeroes` from package `fmtcount`... But I was unable to understand how to mix that command with the answer you gave :(

Comment: I understood as follows: `\csname c@#1\endcsname` would turn the string into the counter name; then you pass that into \@threedigits, that would turn the counter into a real number by using `\ifnum` and `\number` and pad accordingly, right?

Comment: @Igoru I explained it in a littel more detail im my linked answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124983/ It is important that the internal counter representation command (`\@threedigits` in this example) is expandable. I don't know if that is the case for `\padzeroes`...