# customised Symbol-list for Numberstyles other than arabic/roman/alpha, etc

Tags: enumerate, counters

When using `\enumerate` one can enter `\begin{enumerate}[(a)]` and each item will be numbered (a), (b), (c), (d), `\ldots`. Similarly for `\begin{enumerate}[i)]` — one gets i), ii), iii), iv), etc.

I am looking for a defining command, something like

```
\newenumlistcounter{g}{$\alpha$,$\beta$,$\gamma$,$\delta$,$\epsilon$,…,$\omega$}
```

so that when using `\begin{enumerate}[(g)]`, one should get (α), (β), (γ), (δ), (ε), as the item-points.

If someone knows, how to achieve this, I would be grateful, if the same would show me how. (**NOTE: I am looking for a GENERAL solution. Even if there be a pre-built-in option for Greek letters, I would like to be able to do this for completely arbitrary symbol sets.**)

Comment: By »When using `\enumerate`« you mean »when using the `enumerate` package« I guess?

Comment: The easiest way may be to use the `enumitem` package which provides `\AddEnumerateCounter` (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118445) in a combination with custom counter representation commands (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124980/)

Comment: Sorry, this does not help. With this, one can only play with `\alpha,\roman,\arabic`. One cannot via this way, generate one’s OWN lists. The only thing I can think of is something that works with Footnote: one can define ones own symbol-set via `\DefineFNsymbols*{foo}{q,w,e,r,t,y,u,i,o,p,…,m}`, and then one sets `\setfnsymbol{foo}`, which is able to convert a counter-value to a symbol in the defined list. I am hoping for something similar for enumerate.

Comment: In order to show you that my suggestion *does* work I could add an answer using it for Greek letters if you like.

Comment: Thanks, **cg nieder**! **egreg** has answered below, though there remains one question --- whether one can compactify the command usage as one can with i=roman, a=alpha.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a general enumeration style builder.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l_severus_temp_int

\cs_new_protected:Npn \severus_enumeration:nn #1 #2
 {
  \int_case:nvF { #2 } { g_severus_enum_#1_tl } { \use:c { @ctrerr } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_case:nnF { nv }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \severus_define_enumeration:nn #1 #2
 {
  \tl_new:c { g_severus_enum_#1_tl }
  \int_zero:N \l_severus_temp_int
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \int_incr:N \l_severus_temp_int
    \tl_put_right:cx { g_severus_enum_#1_tl }
     {
      {\int_to_arabic:n { \l_severus_temp_int }}
      {\exp_not:n { ##1 }}
     }
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\DefineEnumeration}{mm}
 {
  \cs_new_protected:cpn { #1 } ##1 { \severus_enumeration:nn { #1 } { ##1 } }
  \severus_define_enumeration:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\DefineEnumeration{greekenum}{
  $\alpha$,$\beta$,$\gamma$,$\epsilon$,$\zeta$,% go on
}

\DefineEnumeration{randomenum}{
  Alpher, Bethe, Gamow
}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\greekenum{\arabic*})]
\item\label{alpha} a
\item b
\item c
\end{enumerate}

Here's the reference: \ref{alpha}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\randomenum{\arabic*} --,ref=\randomenum{\arabic*}]
\item\label{X} A
\item B
\item C
\end{enumerate}

Here's the reference: \ref{X}
\end{document}
```

With `\severus_define_enumeration`, the first argument is used for naming a macro and also a token list variable, that will contain data such as

```
{1}{Alpher}{2}{Bethe}{3}{Gamow}
```

in the case of `randomenum`. Such a token list is used when the `\randomenum` macro is used for extracting the desired value. The `\arabic*` bit might be avoided, but it's easier leaving it.

[image]

An `etoolbox` based implementation of the same macros:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\DefineEnumeration}[2]{%
  \expandafter\newrobustcmd\csname #1\endcsname[1]{%
    \severus@enumeration{#1}{##1}%
  }%
  \severus@define@enumeration{#1}{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\severus@enumeration}[2]{%
  \ifcase#2\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\relax\csname severus@#1@list\endcsname
}
\newcommand{\severus@define@enumeration}[2]{%
  \renewcommand{\do}[1]{\csappto{severus@#1@list}{\or##1}}%
  \docsvlist{#2}%
  \csappto{severus@#1@list}{\else\@ctrerr\fi}
}
\makeatother

\DefineEnumeration{greekenum}{
  $\alpha$,$\beta$,$\gamma$,$\epsilon$,$\zeta$,% go on
}

\DefineEnumeration{randomenum}{
  Alpher, Bethe, Gamow
}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\greekenum{\arabic*})]
\item\label{alpha} a
\item b
\item c
\end{enumerate}

Here's the reference: \ref{alpha}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\randomenum{\arabic*} --,ref=\randomenum{\arabic*}]
\item\label{X} A
\item B
\item C
\end{enumerate}

Here's the reference: \ref{X}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Super! Thanks! And is there a way to compactify the usage, so that one can *e. g.* simply enter `\begin{enumerate}[(g):]`? (Similar to how one can use `i`, `a`, etc. for roman, alpha, etc.

Comment: @Severus I'd favor `enumitem` over `enumerate`; it *would* be possible to do that, but it requires substantial work. I think that the `enumitem` way is much clearer.

Comment: Okay, somehow I am getting hiccups with *xparse*… Is there a way to do this, encasing the macros within `\makeatletter … \makeatother` and using `\@…` type definitions?

Comment: @Severus I added the code. However you should update your TeX distribution, since you probably have older versions of `expl3`.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in comments a not so difficult way is to define [new counter representation commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124980/) and tell [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) (rather than [`enumerate`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumerate)) [how to use it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118445/).

The idea is as follows: the internal counter command can be defined using `\ifcase\or ...\or ...\fi` similar to how `\@fnsymbol` is defined.

In order to make this a little bit more comfortable than defining the commands “by hand” we can define a macro that builds the counter representation commands from a csv list. [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) has handy tools to ease this task:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd\csapptocmd[2]{%
  \expandafter\apptocmd\expandafter{\csname#1\endcsname}{#2}{}{}%
}

\newrobustcmd\newcounterlist[2]{%
  \def\@tmplist{}%
  \forcsvlist{\listadd\@tmplist}{#2}%
  % build the internal counter command:
  \csdef{@#1}##1{\ifcase##1}%
  \def\do##1{\csapptocmd{@#1}{\or##1}}%
  \dolistloop\@tmplist
  \csapptocmd{@#1}{\else\@ctrerr\fi}%
  % define the counter interface command:
  \csdef{#1}##1{\expandafter\csname @#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname c@##1\endcsname}%
}

% new counter lists:
\newcounterlist{greeklabel}{$\alpha$,$\beta$,$\gamma$}% add more
\newcounterlist{whatever}{aaa,bbb,ccc}% add more

% tell enumitem how to use the new counter representations:
\AddEnumerateCounter{\greeklabel}{\@greeklabel}{1}
\AddEnumerateCounter{\whatever}{\@whatever}{1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\greeklabel*)]
  \item first item
  \item second item \label{beta}
  \item third item
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\itshape\whatever* ---,ref=\whatever*]
  \item first item
  \item second item
  \item third item \label{ccc}
\end{enumerate}

see \ref{beta} and \ref{ccc}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For adding new counter representation commands to `enumerate`'s mechanism one needs to redefine `\@enloop@`. Below is a suggestion that does it via patching the command with `etoolbox`'s `\patchcmd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd\csapptocmd[2]{%
  \expandafter\apptocmd\expandafter{\csname#1\endcsname}{#2}{}{}%
}

\newrobustcmd\newcounterlist[2]{%
  \def\@tmplist{}%
  \forcsvlist{\listadd\@tmplist}{#2}%
  % build the internal counter command:
  \csdef{@#1}##1{\ifcase##1}%
  \def\do##1{\csapptocmd{@#1}{\or##1}}%
  \dolistloop\@tmplist
  \csapptocmd{@#1}{\else\@ctrerr\fi}%
  % define the counter interface command:
  \csdef{#1}##1{\expandafter\csname @#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname c@##1\endcsname}%
}

% new counter lists:
\newcounterlist{greeklabel}
  {$\alpha$,$\beta$,$\gamma$,$\delta$,$\epsilon$,$\zeta$,$\eta$,$\iota$,$\theta$}% add more
\newcounterlist{whatever}{aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff,ggg,hhh,iii}% add more

% adding the new counter commands to enumerate's mechanism:
\newrobustcmd*\addenumeratelabel[2]{%
  \patchcmd\@enloop@
    {\ifx 1\@entemp \def\@tempa{\@enLabel\arabic}\else}% search
    {%
      \ifx 1\@entemp \def\@tempa{\@enLabel\arabic}\else
      \ifx #1\@entemp \def\@tempa{\@enLabel#2}\else
    }% replace
    {}% success
    {}% failure
  \patchcmd\@enloop@
    {\fi}% search
    {\fi\fi}% replace
    {}% success
    {}% failure
}
\addenumeratelabel{g}{\greeklabel}
\addenumeratelabel{w}{\whatever}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tracingmacros=1

\begin{enumerate}[(g)]
  \item first item
  \item second item \label{beta}
  \item third item
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[\itshape w ---]
  \item first item
  \item second item
  \item third item \label{ccc}
\end{enumerate}

see \ref{beta} and \ref{ccc}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why `\csapptocmd` instead of the simplest `\csappto` (that's predefined)?

Comment: @egreg `\appto` doesn't like macros with parameters

Comment: I see; sorry, I thought it was a parameterless macro.